# Is there a built-in .NET method for getting all of the properties and values for an object?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have:

```
public class Item
{
    public string SKU {get; set; }
    public string Description {get; set; }
}

....
```

Is there a built-in method in .NET that will let me get the properties and values for variable `i` of type `Item` that might look like this:

```
{SKU: "123-4556", Description: "Millennial Radio Classic"}
```

I know that `.ToString()` can be overloaded to provide this functionaility, but I couldn't remember if this was already provided in .NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format you've described as an example looks a lot like [JSON](http://www.json.org/), so you could use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
string value = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myItem);
```

Comment: I guess my brain has been in JSON mode lately.  I'm really just looking for an easy way to print out an object in the console, but yes, it definately looks like JSON.

Answer (score 5):

If it is not JSON you are using and just normal C# class, have alook at [**System.Reflection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) namespace

something similar would work

```
Item item = new Item();
foreach (PropertyInfo info in item.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   if (info.CanRead)
   {

      // To retrieve value 
      object o = info.GetValue(myObject, null);

      // To Set Value
      info.SetValue("SKU", "NewValue", null);
   }
}
```

Provided with, you should have `proper` `get` and `set` in place for the `properties` you want to work over.

Answer (score 1):

The XMLSerializer will work as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JSON library such as [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) or the built-in [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).