# See all an object's properties and values (including child objects)

Tags: .net, reflection, properties

I was wondering if there was a built in feature in .Net that could output (at runtime) all the properties and values in a given object and, if possible, even including sub-objects.

I'm thinking of Reflection or [XML Serializion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and saw [some people mentioned JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730734/is-there-a-built-in-net-method-for-getting-all-of-the-properties-and-values-for), but can't really figure out how to do it the right way... Does anyone know if this is possibly a built in feature in .Net or if there's a good example / tool that either already does this or could guide me in the right direction?

Comment: For what purpose? Debugging? Serialization?

Comment: Reflection does do this, that's how Reflector and DotPeek work.

Comment: Sorry, @Matthew, for debugging purposes

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx

Comment: Thanks @PinnyM- But as I said on Mohammed's answer below, I was morseso wondering if there was a pre-created tool / .Net feature that kinda just spat out ALL the information about the data held within my object since I figure that otherwise, I'd have to write dozens of case statements to get the child object data (for example, supposing I had a List(of DataRow) or something similar), I was just wondering if there was a pre-set tool that already had this kind of functionality / knew how to pull the correct properties from the most common types of objects and spit out their values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s92ee1.aspx) class or take a look at the [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) framework.

Comment: @abatishchev hahahaha `System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: @Alechandro, as I'm seeing what others are saying, it does seem like the correct way to go here is one of those 2 methods... HOPEFULLY someone has a better suggestion, but this does seem to be th best I can find so far. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help (a little)... JSON.Net is pretty straight forward, believe you can work with that. ;)

Comment: ... I played around and this did prove to be the best way to go - Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

To see all the public properties and values of an object:

```
foreach(var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) //note: you can pass in binding flags to GetProperties to get static, private, etc properties
{
    var propVal = prop.GetValue(obj);

    //prop has information such as Name, PropertyType
    //propVal is the value of that property for obj
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed - Even though I figure I could write a loop, I was morseso wondering if there was a pre-created tool / .Net feature that kinda just spat out ALL the information about the data held within my object since I figure that otherwise, I'd have to write dozens of case statements to get the child object data (for example, supposing I had a `List(of DataRow)` or something similar), I was just wondering if there was a pre-set tool that already had this kind of functionality / knew how to pull the correct properties from the most common types of objects and spit out their values...

Comment: I see. For cases such as a IEnumerable/IList/etc, you can probably do something hacky like checking the prop.Name.BeginsWith("ICollection") and then cast it to a ICollection<object> and recursively output its properties that way. I agree, however, that a tool would be more suited for what you need.

Comment: +1 for the good idea, but it turned out `XMLSerialization` proved to be the best route for me to take - Thanks!!